# adding a cell to table using add button

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a **Dynamic table** in Angular.js, in which the user inputs number of columns, in a *text box* provided. Then add buttons are provided under **each** column to *add* as much cells as user wants. The cell will only be added to *that* column only.
I am using **ng-repeat** to  repeat the number of columns and *add* buttons.
I am able to get the response of the user in a variable, ie, the *column* under which the user wants to add the cell.
Can someone please give me a **controller** to add a cell to the selected *column* either by using ng-repeat , ng-model or without it.
my table code looks somewhat like this:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="n in arr track by $index">SET {{n.setalpha}} </th><!--table heading, dont mind this-->
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="<!--something goes here-->">
            <!--<select ng-model="name" ng-options="options.topicname for options in topics"></select>-->
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="n in arr track by $index">
                <button ng-click="addSelected($index+1)">add{{$index+1}}</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

where: `n in arr track by $index` , is used to repeat the table *heading* and *add* button say 'n' number of times and `addSelected($index+1)` is a function whose controller is:

```
$scope.addSelected = function (setno) {
    console.log(setno);
    $scope.thisset = setno;

}
```

, `$scope.thisset` is the variable in which i have the response of the user, ie, the *column* under which the user wants to add a cell.
**NOTE**: I want to add the cell in column only under which the user wants. NOT in all columns.  MY CODE:

```js
var app = angular.module('topicSelector', []);


app.controller('topicController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.arr = [];
    $scope.thisset = -1; //tells in which set, cell has to added.



    $scope.topics = [
        {
            topicid: "1",
            topicname: "history"
        },
        {
            topicid: "2",
            topicname: "geography"
        },
        {
            topicid: "3",
            topicname: "maths"
        }
    ];








    $scope.DefineSets = function () {

        for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.no_of_sets; i++) {
            $scope.arr.push({
                setno: i,
                setalpha: String.fromCharCode(64 + i)
            });

        };
    };

    $scope.addSelected = function (setno) {
        console.log(setno);
        $scope.thisset = setno;

    }



});
```

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="topicSelector">

<head>
    <title>
        topic selector
    </title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Enter number of sets:</h3>
    <div ng-controller="topicController">
        <form ng-submit="DefineSets()">
            <input type="text" ng-model="no_of_sets" placeholder="number of sets" name="no_of_sets">
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
        <br>
        <br>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="n in arr track by $index">SET {{n.setalpha}} </th>
            </tr>
            <!--<tr ng-repeat="">
    <select ng-model="name" ng-options="options.topicname for options in topics"></select>
</tr>-->
            <tr>
                <td ng-repeat="n in arr track by $index">
                    <button ng-click="addSelected($index+1)">add{{$index+1}}</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>



    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**LINK TO PLUNK** [PLUNK](https://plnkr.co/edit/gb7KlQ?p=preview)

Comment: Please create a plunker with your code.  That will help us help you.

Comment: What version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: Angular 1, version 1.5.6

Comment: @jbrown i have added the link

Comment: IMHO a table is not the best element for your problem. A combination horizontal and vertical flex boxes implemented with lists should be better, if you do not have any restrictions on that matter.

Comment: @VictorHarraiz no there are no restrictions. Can you plz give me a detailed description for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example I used lists instead of tables with fle display, IMHO it is a better approach:

```js
(function (angular) {
"use strict";
  function GrowController ($log) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.cols = [];
    vm.size = 0;
    vm.sizeChanged = function () {
      var size = vm.size, cols = vm.cols,
          diff = size - cols.length;
      $log.debug("Size changed to", size, cols);
      if (diff > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
          cols.push([]);
        }
      } else {
        cols.splice(diff, -diff);
      }
    };
    vm.addCell = function (index) {
      var cols = vm.cols;
      $log.debug("Cell added in column", index);
      cols[index].push(index + "." + cols[index].length);
    };
  }

   angular.module("app",[])
        .controller("GrowController", ["$log", GrowController]);
}(angular));
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.cols {
  display: flex;
}
.cells {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
button.add-cell {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="GrowController as $ctrl" ng-app="app" ng-strict-di>
<p>
    <label for="size">Number of columns(0-10):</label>
    <input id="size" type="number" ng-model="$ctrl.size" ng-change="$ctrl.sizeChanged()" min="0" max="10">
</p>
<ul class="cols" ng-if="$ctrl.cols.length">
    <li ng-repeat="col in $ctrl.cols">
        <button class="add-cell-button" ng-click="$ctrl.addCell($index)">Add cell</button>
        <ul class="cells" ng-if="col.length">
            <li ng-repeat="cell in col">{{ ::cell }}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Anyway, I Angularjs 1.5.6 you should consider using "Components" instead of "Controllers" and "one-side" bindings.

Comment: thanks a lot! i used your as a template to complete mine. :) Although I was not bale to figure out few things, like, what is the use of `"use strict";`? and how does this `{{ ::cell }}` work?

Comment: :: is a "one time binding"